# does tabulator have scroll callback available for mouse scroll and bar scroll within the table?

Tags: tabulator

Can't seem to find the scroll callback when table is scrolled using mouse wheel or scroll bar within a tabulator table. Did I just not find it or does tabulator not provide it natively?

Comment: No, you have to provide it natively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by dota2pro Tabulator does not have this feature as of now. I was only able to find callbacks for post `scrollToRow()` or `scrollToColumn()` successful scrolls to desired location.

Answer (score 0):

for Tabulator version 4.5, the correct selector should be **.tabulator .tabulator-tableHolder**

If you are using jQuery, you could make a callback like this:

```
$('.tabulator .tabulator-tableHolder').on('scroll',function(){
    // do something when user scrolls the table
})
```